# how to concat/merge two columns with different length?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, permutation, flatten, google-query-language

I'm new to google sheet. I have a column(E) with the date and another with a session(F), I want to merge them into one column with each date & different session just like the first few rows in column C.

[image]

I've tried "=ArrayFormula(concat(D2:D,concat(" ",F2:F5)))" in column C but only got the first date.

Comment: I think you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086881/merge-two-python-pandas-data-frames-of-different-length-but-keep-all-rows-in-out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(FILTER(E2:E, E2:E<>"")&" "&
           TRANSPOSE(FILTER(F2:F, F2:F<>""))), "where not Col1 starts with ' '", ))
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775825/5632629

Answer (score 0):

In your cell C1, try this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(E1:E&" "&F1:F)`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply do concatenate cells like this:

CONCATENATE(E1, " ", F1)

to get what you want I think.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [cartesian product](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761). I don't have a single formula that does the entire thing for you, but I can suggest a two-step approach.

Get the cartesian product with this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(E2:E9 & "|" & TRANSPOSE(F2:F5)), "|"))
```

This gives a pair of each date against each time in two result columns. You can then concatenate each row of them in a final result column.